# Gigya SDK crashing on Facebook auth

Tags: ios, facebook, gigya

starting today I found that the Gigya login procedure is crashing (inside the lib) with the message: "Logging in with Facebook is supported only using Facebook SDK native login". It's using the auth flow, worked fine before and I haven't touched a thing. I'm integrating both using Cocoapods.

Comment: Not an answer, but a workaround;
I changed a line in the Podfile to avoid the obvious update issue:

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'

into

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.23.2'

so it avoids any support issues with Facebook iOS SDK 4 with was released 5 days ago. 

Runs fine now.

Comment: How you have resolved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The Gigya Cocoapod was not created by and therefore isn't supported by Gigya.  Gigya has had a number of customers reporting serious problems with its inclusion which range from app crashes to compiler failures.

Because of this, you should instead follow the [method of including the Gigya iOS SDK](http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/iOS#iOS-a.AddGigyaSDKFrameworktoYourApplication'sXcodeProject) that is outlined in Gigya's documentation for your project.

Additionally, you must also [include the Facebook SDK](http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/iOS#iOS-AddingFacebookNativeLogin) as outlined in Gigya's documentation.  Unfortunately, this also precludes the use of the Facebook Cocoapod due to way Cocoapods dynamically binds the Facebook SDK which prevents the Gigya SDK from finding it at run time.

Comment: I followed the instructions of installation for FB-SDK, version 4.4 that supported by Gigya, but the FB login does not work and always returns "Logging in with Facebook is supported only using Facebook SDK native login" :(

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've updated the solution to include information regarding the FB-SDK.

Comment: I’ve followed everything here and am still seeing this with the Gigya SDK version 3.4.2 and Facebook SDK version 4.7.1.